# How can I make selection based on conditions on SQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql

There is a table based on ID an those ID's status keys:

[The table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RH1CI.png)

I need to write query that will bring higher status key of the same ID. For example; query will bring only the row with status key number 9 for ID number 123. But it will bring the row with status key number 2 for ID number 156.

Hope I managed to explain myself clearly. Please help me with this query.

Answer (score 2):

Use `max()` aggregation

```
select id, max(status_key)
from tablename
group by id
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't tag your backend, this would work with many backends and older versions of many backends (assuming you have other columns too in your table - otherwise do only group by):

```
select myTable.* 
from myTable 
inner join 
(select id, max(statusKey) as statusKey
from myTable
group by id) tmp on myTable.id = tmp.id and myTable.statusKey = tmp.statusKey;
```